# Want to solve a simple system of equations for $x$ without conditions

Tags: equation-solving

I'd like to solve a simple system of equations

$\qquad r = (a - b)/b,\,b = e + f,\,e = g\,h,\,g = j\,x$

for $x$.

but I want the output to be in one line without conditions, something like:

$\qquad x= e/h/j\,f$

How can I do this?

Answer (score 5):

This might be what you are after

```
equations = {r == (a - b)/b, b == e + f, e == g*h, g == j*x}
(* {r == (a - b)/b, b == e + f, e == g h, g == j x} *)

Solve[Eliminate[equations, {g, a, f}], x]
(* {{x -> e/(h j)}} *)
```

Comment: Thanks! Eliminate does what I want.

Comment: `Solve` takes an optional argument of a `List` of variables to be eliminated:

`Solve[equations, x, {g, a, f}]`. Although this is no longer documented, it still works.